# How to center a button above a tableview with the storyboard in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I would like to get this result (storyboard view):

[image]

But when I simulate my app, I get this result (without any constraints)

[image]

So I tried to add some constraints to center the table view. But when I add any constrain, the TableView disappears. Why?

Comment: Because you didn't add proper constraint.

Comment: And what's the proper constraint?? :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all old constraint first and set constraint as shown in below images:

**For Button:**

[image]

**For TableView:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I did it the same way like you! And when I simulate the app, the TableView disappears!

Comment: do you remove old constraint?

Comment: it is tableview's default behaviour but you can increase left side distance.

Comment: Ohhhh okay.... I understand... I'm not so familiar with Apples design pattern. How can I increase that? Yes I will up vote your post! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: just click on that left side constraint and change constant value to anything you need from Attribute inspector.

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

As below, add two constraints is enough.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No that doesn't work. The scan button is already centered. I try to center the TableView below, too. And that doesn't work with an easy center command...

Answer (score 0):

You should have 4 constraints for the button:
to the top
to the left (alternatively to the middle)
to the right (alternatively constant width)
constant height

And 4 to the tableview:
the top to the bottom of the button
to the left
to the right
to the bottom of the screen

Check out this tutorial if you dont understand autolayout: http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Comment: i don't suggest you do this cause you will have issues with rotation